# How to tell If 2 Metamask wallets were created from the same seed phrase?

Tags: metamask, security, privacy

When you first create a MetaMask wallet, it is also possible to add on more wallet addresses by pressing **Create Account**, so that your MetaMask has Wallet #1, Wallet #2 and so on. All of these wallets therefore will have the exact same seed phrase because they were spawned in the same MetaMask.

Is there anything on Etherscan or the Ethereum blockchain that indicates that Wallet address #2 was spawned are was created in the same MetaMask extension as Wallet address #1? and that they have, and belong to, the exact same seed phrase?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the public addresses are from hashing the private key (seed phrase).

Comment: thanks. why does hashing the seed phrase cause the two different addresses to completely dissociate, technically?